# Finding the length of the longest run in a very long generated sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded

So I am trying to calculate the longest run of `True`'s in a boolean sequence in Python. The sequence is very long (>10^10) and so it's not possible to generate it in reasonable time, let alone store it in memory. Instead, I generate the n-th item in the sequence. Is a more efficient algorithm in terms of speed possible, without multiprocessing or statistical analysis of the sequence? Abstracting away the details of the generator, the code looks like this:

```
run = 1
record = 1
i = 0
while i < sequence_length:
    if nth_place(i): 
        for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
            if nth_place(j): run += 1
            else: break

        for j in range(i+1, sequence_lengh):
            if nth_place(i): run += 1
            else:
                if run > record: record = run
                run = 1
                i = j
                break

    i += (record + 1)
```

Description: Instead of checking every position, the algorithm makes jumps of size of current record+1. If the result is `False` then it jumps again and repeats - this ensures that the longest run that could be missed has at most the length of current record. If the result is `True`, then it starts counting backwards until it reaches a `False`. Then it picks up from (i+1)-th place and continues counting forwards until it reaches a `False`. If the counted run is longer than the current record, the record gets updated. i gets updated too, and the algorithm repeats, now jumpring from the current position.

---

Full description as follows:
I am trying to calculate the longest possible run of pairs of numbers of format (6n+1,6n-1) between pairs of [twin primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime), that are created by the first m primes. 
For this, I have a list of m primes that are greater than 3 and for each prime in the list there is associated boolean sequence of according length, with `False` everywhere except at positions `p//3` and `p-(p//3)-1`. For example, given a list `[5,7]`, the list of associated sequences is `[[0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0]]`. 
The long sequence that the question is about is then generated by cyclically iterating the sequences and storing the logical disjunction. For example:

```
01010010100101001010010100101001010
00101000010100001010000101000010100
-----------------------------------
01111010110101001010010101101011110
```

Generating the sequence is fine for small lists of primes, but as the number of primes increases, the sequence grows with [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) time complexity, which is worse than factorial. Therefore I can't generate the whole sequence, but only get the n-th term. The full program is here:
(the function in question is `count_ones`)

```
import math

def is_prime(n): #checks whether a given number is prime
    if n == 2: return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n <= 1: return False

    sqr = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1

    for divisor in range(3, sqr, 2):
        if n % divisor == 0: return False
    return True

def next_prime(current_prime): #returns the next prime
    if current_prime == 2: return 3

    counter = current_prime + 2
    while 1:
        if is_prime(counter): return counter
        counter += 2

def get_pattern(n): #generates a pattern of a prime
    lis = [False for x in range(n)]
    lis[n//3] = True
    lis[n-(n//3)-1] = True
    return lis

def list_product(lis): #computes the product of a list of numbers
    product = 1
    for i in range(len(lis)): product *= lis[i]
    return product

def nth_place(patterns,primes,n):
    for a,b in zip(patterns, primes):
        if a[n%b]: return True
    else:
        return False

def count_ones(patterns,primes):
    if primes[-1] == 5: return 1 #skip trivial case with a single prime 5

    for i in patterns: i = dict(enumerate(i)) 
    primes = tuple(primes) 
    patterns = tuple(patterns) 

    run = 1
    record = 1
    #since the sequence is symmetrical, we'll need only half of it
    sequence_length = list_product(primes)//2 + 1 
    i = 0

    while i < sequence_length:
        if nth_place(patterns, primes, i): 
            for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
                if nth_place(patterns, primes, j): run += 1
                else: break

            for j in range(i+1, sequence_length):
                if nth_place(patterns, primes, j): run += 1
                else:
                    if run > record: record = run
                    run = 1
                    i = j
                    break

        i += (record + 1)

    return record


def main():
    number_of_primes = 6 #change this value
    prime = 3
    primes = []
    patterns = []

    for i in range(number_of_primes):
        prime = next_prime(prime)
        primes.append(prime)
        patterns.append(get_pattern(prime))

    record = count_ones(patterns,primes)
    print('{} - {}'.format(primes,record))

main()
```

---

A minor and obvious improvement that I missed in the main loop of `count_ones` function: allocate a separate variable to hold the value of `record+1` and recalculate it only when the current record itself changes, instead of every iteration of the loop.

Comment: It would help if you could add the implementation of `nth_place`. This way, your code could actually be run by the reviewers and they can check themselves if the alternatives they propose are actually better.

Comment: @Graipher this is actually a bit tricky to explain without context. I tried to explain how the whole program works.

Comment: `sequence_lengh` in snippet isn't quite correct. I have difficulties recognising said snippet in `The full program`: could you factor out the predicate (`nth_place()`)?

Comment: @greybeard sorry for causing confusion, I edited the full program to be more analogous to the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Checking from the end of a promising index range intending to leap as far ahead as possible, thereby reducing the number of checks, is the [way to go](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore_algorithm#Description).
There is nothing special about the indexes you start to check from:
Why start checking upwards without knowing there's a new record?

Work in progress: not named, not documented, not tested

```
target = 1
''' record if met '''
good = 0
''' number of good indices seen '''
bad = -1
''' known bad index '''
while bad < length - target:
    goal = bad + target  # if predicate(bad+1 .. goal): new record
    for check in range(goal, bad + good, -1):  # exclude known good
        if not predicate(check):
            good = goal - check  # may be lower than before
            bad = check
            break
    else:  # new record!
        for goal in range(goal + 1, length):
            if not predicate(goal):
                good = 0
                break
        target = goal - bad
        bad = goal  # not really if above for-loop terminated normally
record = target - 1
```

(Where record lengths are more likely at the end of a sequence, reverse before or invert `range()`s & such.)

Comment: (What to call `ugly`?)

Comment: (Going to remain unfinished for lack of zeal.)